# How do find/remove duplicate e-mail addresses in one column?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a file with multiple columns and one of the columns has the persons email address. Is there a way to search for any email address that is in the column more than once?

I could try and list them alphabetically, but in some of the cells there is more than one email address, so if it isn't listed first,...

I just want to make sure that the same person/email address is not listed twice.

Now if the directions to do this is by using a formula, could you please be specific on the steps I need to take? I never use formulas and am naive on how they work and what the different codes mean.

The column with the email addresses is column Z and there are about 2200 rows.

Comment: If you have no inclination to figuring out the code, then i suggest manually go line by line and put each address on its own line, then sort and filter out the dupes.  it will take an hour or two, or maybe you get lucky here and someone writes it for you...

Answer (score 0):

As Joe T said in the comments, you must be lucky to find someone that will write the code for you and he is right, SO is not a place to ask for ready made code but since the "*duplicate in a spreadsheet*" is probably the most popular subject for years and since your use case introduces a new parameter (multiple values in a cell) I found it might be worth giving you a hint.

Since I didn't want to spend to much time on this, I kept it simple and straightforward and went only half way...(it could be enhanced and might have some weaknesses)

This script adds a column in your SS and writes a `X` in every row that has a duplicate.

It does not delete anything because I considered it is impossible to decide which one to delete when one of the item has multiple emails and another a single one (or a different pair but with a common value...) so you will have to decide which one you delete but the `X` will definitely help ! (sort on column `AA` to make it even easier!)

code below :

```
function highlightDuplicates() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sh.insertColumnAfter(26).getRange(1,27).setValue('duplicates');
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift();// remove headers from data
  data.sort(function (x,y){// sort on column Z
   var xp = x[25];
   var yp = y[25];
   return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
 });  
  for(var n in data){
    var row = data[n];
    var email = row[25]
    for(var d in data){
      if((data[d][25].indexOf(email)>-1 || email.indexOf(data[d][25])>-1) && d!=n){
        row[26]='X';// if common data, mark with X
      }
    }
    data[n]=row;// update date
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);//update sheet
}
```

[image]